# Flutter mysql insert dont work real device

Tags: mysql, flutter

I am using flutter and developing a reminder app. I want to insert database after then notification created. These codes run the emulator. After installing the application on the real device, it does not insert. what could be the reason?

I call function IconButton pressed.

```
 createOrganizerNotification(
        taskName, time, taskDate, nt, sm, taskIcon);
```

And I create notification(success) and call insert table function.

```
void createOrganizerNotification(var taskName, var taskTime, var taskDate,
    var notificationTitle, var seeMore, var taskIcon) async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var email = preferences.getString("usermail");
  var time = taskTime.split(':');
  var date = taskDate.split('-');
  taskIcon = taskIcon.split('"');
  await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
        id: createUniqueId(),
        channelKey: 'notification_channel',
        title: notificationTitle,
        body: taskDate + ' - ' + taskTime + ' - ' + taskName,
      ),
      /*actionButtons: [
        NotificationActionButton(
          key: 'see_more',
          label: seeMore,
        )
      ],*/
      schedule: NotificationCalendar(
          day: int.parse(date[0]),
          month: int.parse(date[1]),
          year: int.parse(date[2]),
          hour: int.parse(time[0]),
          minute: int.parse(time[1])));
  await DBHelper().insertOrganizerNotification(
      email,
      date[0].toString(),
      date[1].toString(),
      date[2].toString(),
      time[0].toString(),
      time[1].toString(),
      taskName.toString(),
      'created',
      taskIcon[1].toString());
}
```

This is insert to database function.

```
Future<bool> insertOrganizerNotification(
    String email,
    String day,
    String month,
    String year,
    String hour,
    String minute,
    String title,
    String status,
    String icon,
  ) async {
    try {
      final conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(
        ConnectionSettings(
            host: _host,
            port: _port,
            user: _user,
            password: _password,
            db: _db),
      );
      await conn.query(
          'insert into OrganizerNotificaitonsList ( Email, Day, Month, Year, Hour, Minute, Title, Status, Icon ) values ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
          [email, day, month, year, hour, minute, title, status, icon]);
      await conn.close();
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

And this is my table structure.
[image]

Really I don't understand this bug. Because the emulator can insert the database successfully. Only real devices have this bug.

Answer (score 2):

Check the database connection settings and update the host, to an IP or domain.
On the emulator the localhost will be allowed as device and database are on same network

```
  var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
  host: 'localhost', 
  port: 3306,
  user: 'bob',
  password: '*****',
  db: 'mydb'
  );
  var conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like internet permissions issue. add the following permission before the Application section, to the Manifest file of your app.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Without internet permission your app won't be able to send or receive requests or data from the internet thus preventing SQL operations.

and if you are using a database on the local host it won't work on a device as the device will not be able to access it. so use a database on a cloud server.